# Increase the length of hline marker in matplotlib

Tags: matplotlib

I want to plot data using a constant, not too small, horizontal line for each value.

It seems the way to do it is with

```
x = np.arange(0, 10, 2)
y = [2,3,4,1,7]
plt.scatter(x, y, marker="_")
plt.legend(loc='Height')
plt.show()
```

but the horizontal lines are too small. Can they be customized to some greater length, at least a length similar to thewidth of a bar plot? Thx.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you mean that you want to increase marker **size**?

```
plt.scatter(x, y, marker="_", s=400)
```

[image: s=400]

`s=1000`

[image: s=1000]